# session is not working when deploy app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

The sessions is working in my local machine but when i deploys the app, the sessions don't working.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException 
{
     String UserName = req.getParameter("username");
     HttpSession request = req.getSession();
     request.setAttribute("UserName", UserName);
     request.setAttribute("Reload", "true");
     res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
     //http://demoapp04071992.appspot.com/
     //res.sendRedirect("http://127.0.0.1:8888/FileSharingDemo.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
     res.sendRedirect("http://demoapp04071992.appspot.com/FileSharingDemo.html");
}
```

when i run in local, i use the url 127.0.0.1. When i deploy, i use the url demoapp04071992. But sessions is lost and i can't get the user name when user logins.

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving a `username` parameter in request? Also, when sending a redirect, you should use `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath` to attach the context of the application automatically, so you don't need to hardcode `http://demoapp04071992.appspot.com/` (or whatever URL is behind), and concatenate it with your desired URL e.g. `"FileSharingDemo.html"`.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE you have to activate session support, it's not enabled by default. Here is an official link:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?csw=1#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions